# can LinearLayout put two items on the same line?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

I have the code as below, and I need 2 things:
I wish to put `tv[i]` on the same line as `txt[i]`
and I want `keyboard` to appear after touching `tv[i]`.

I'm a complete beginner to Android. Thank you.

```
public void click2(View view) {
        Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3.setText("hello");
       // Button[] buttons = new Button[10](this);
        /*
       LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        Button txt1 = new Button(this);
       // linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        linearLayout.addView(txt1);
*/

        Integer.toBinaryString(12);

        // Put buttons into an array
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
       // GridLayout gridLayout=(GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

        // Put buttons into an array
     //   Button[] txt = {new Button(this), new Button(this)};
        Button[] txt = new Button[8];
        TextView[] tv = new TextView[8];

        // loop over all values of i between 0 to the end of the button array
        for (int i = 0; i < txt.length; i = i + 1) {
            // Access array elements by index so txt1 is txt[1], etc.
       txt[i]=new Button(this);
       txt[i].setText(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
            linearLayout.addView(txt[i]);
            tv[i]=new TextView(this);

            linearLayout.addView(tv[i]);

        }

        };
```

MAYBE I'm putting your line
`linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);`
at a wrong place.

KOD MainActivity.java

```
public void click2(View view) {
        Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3.setText("hello");

        // Put buttons into an array
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
       // GridLayout gridLayout=(GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

        // Put buttons into an array
     //   Button[] txt = {new Button(this), new Button(this)};
        Button[] txt = new Button[8];
        TextView[] tv = new TextView[8];

        // loop over all values of i between 0 to the end of the button array
        for (int i = 0; i < txt.length; i = i + 1) {
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            // Access array elements by index so txt1 is txt[1], etc.
       txt[i]=new Button(this);
       txt[i].setText(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
            linearLayout.addView(txt[i]);
            tv[i]=new TextView(this);

            linearLayout.addView(tv[i]);


        }

        };
```

Comment: `LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);`  I think you are referencing your layout, and this is wrong please check your code.

Comment: @RaBaKa78 Sorry I didn't catch the point. What do you mean by the line `LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);` ? Can I use LinearLayout ? I do not know what's wrong with my code, I've been using AS for one week only.

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

to make 2 items appear side by side.

For showing keyboard, take a look here:
[How do you close/hide the Android soft keyboard programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-do-you-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard-programmatically)

Comment: Please look at my EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are referencing your xml file here:
`LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);`

You should go to your xml file, add a id (`android:id="@+id/some_id"`) tag to your `<LinearLayout>` and use this id in your `LinearLayout linearLayout =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.HERE)`

Other option is to go to your xml file and add `sandroid:orientation="horizontal"` like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/some_id"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    ...>
```